# Custom CSS only to articles

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to apply a css rule only to my articles. I created the following code, but it did not work.

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_css_if_post_type_is_post' );

function custom_css_if_post_type_is_post() {                
    if ( is_single() && 'post' == get_post_type() ) {
        echo '<style type="text/css">
                 .post-thumb {
                    display: none!Important;
                  }
             </style>'; 
    }   
}
```

What I doing wrong?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress usually automatically puts certain classes into the `body` tag, depending on and related to the post type, the used template etc.

So to achieve what you want, you could use the following CSS rule (no need for PHP, Wordpress functions or Javascript):

```
.post-type-post .post-thumb {
    display: none !important;
}
```

The `.post-type-post` class will only appear in the `body` tag of *posts*  and therfore the rule will only apply to the `.post-thumb` class on html pages which are of type *post*.

Answer (score 0):

By default, WordPress sets various classes to  depending on which page, template, parent, .. you are on. For a single post, some of these are single and single-post, so you could use the following

```
body.single.single-post .post-thumb {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Will work 100%, if still there is an issue let me know